# How to handle 3rd party libraries in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

At my work we are just starting to use TFS with our team of 4 developers, and are at the same time transitioning from single developer projects to team projects.  We are mostly using the default settings in TFS

I was the first to push up a simple Silverlight MVVM project consisting of a solution with a Silverlight and a web project.

When my team-mate pulled down my code and tried to compile, he was faced with many missing references (.dlls), Expression blend SDK, Ria Services toolkit, Telerik controls, simple mvvm toolkit, silverlight toolkit, etc.

**What do we need to do, to add projects to TFS that have everything needed to be compile it when the next developer pulls it down?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a really good way to do this all automatically. What you'd generally do this this:

- in your branch create a bin folder next to your src folder.
- in the bin folder create folders for each component you're relying on
- in each folder place the setup or a link to the setup
- in each folder place the binary files you're using in your solution
- in each folder place a readme with any manual steps that must be completed
- if wanted you can create a powershell script or batch file which installs all required components. It isn't too hard to [detect whether or not an application is already installed using powershell and wmi](http://techibee.com/powershell/check-if-a-application-is-installed-or-not-using-powershell/365)

Now you'll have to fix a few things in your solution:

- make sure your references don't point to the GAC, but that they point to the assemblies inside the bin folder of your branch
- make sure all the paths are relative to the solution. Any c:... paths will not carry over from one system to another

I found that the easiest way to do this is to unload the project in Visual Studio and then edit it. You can then quickly add `hintpath="..\..\..\bin\component` attributes to each reference. There are [a few blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manishagarwal/archive/2005/09/28/474769.aspx) on [this subject](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheDependencyWhateverdllCannotBeCopiedToTheRunDirectoryBecauseItWouldConflictWithTheDependancy.aspx) which provide different solutions which all solve this same issue.

This setup allows you to at least get the latest version of any solution and build it without having to install any tools. If some of your components rely on visual studio add-ins, then the designers for these tools usually won't work, but at least you're able to build them.

An often used alternative is to create a Virtual Machine base image for your project and install all the required components onto it. Then copy the image to each developers workstation and sysprep it to ensure they all have a unique name and identifiers. When the project needs to update its dependencies, let one developer create a new clean machine and re-distribute that to all team members.

If you're using Windows Server Virtualization or VMWare, it's quite easy to create differencing disks and allow developers to access these images remotely.

Another approach would be to [use NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) and [script NuGet using a powershell script](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/05/NuGetPowerShellConsole.aspx) for your solution. This will work for most cases, but products like Expression Blend still need to be installed separately.

Comment: Thanks for the response (I was hoping it was a configuration setting or something a little simpler to maintain).  So, what happens x months(or even years) down the road, when you need to make a simple bug fix in the code in TFS, but the libraries on your box are newer and may have changes that effect how or if you TFS('old') code will compile?

Comment: In the VM version of the story: 
 - You'd look up the correct snapshot
 - You'd apply that and fix the bug

|| In the non-VM version:
 - You're in trouble and need to manually remove the new tools (the binaries would be part of your sourcecontrol label/branch, so the build would work fine if you don't rely on Add-ons/ins other than assemblies).

Comment: @MongooseNX if you have a proper branch structure by, say, having a branch for each release, then it won't matter if you have newer binaries because the older version can be downloaded from the old release branch. If you follow jesse's suggestion (by referencing binaries from the bin folder and not the GAC) then there are no issues. We do this at work and it works flawlessly. No need to over complicate things. And you can get around the relative path issue if everybody on your team uses the same path - which is possible in a standards-based development environment.